# ActiveAdmin csv Export belongs_to and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Is there a way to get ActiveAdmin to export belongs_to and has_one inside a resource? I have a resource `Members` and it will export the columns of `Members` but not any column that is a `belongs_to` or `has_one`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to configure the `csv` section of the ActiveAdmin resource. See the full documentation of [CSV Format](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/4-csv-format.md) for more details.

An example is the following, but it requires that every column be specified.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Member do
  csv do
    column(:name)
    column(:team_name) { |member| member.team.name }
    column(:created_at)
  end
end
```